# Isn't there any analog between angular momenta in Classical/Quantum Mechanics, especially for the ground state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, ground-state

By the ground state, I mean something like the state of the hydrogen atom with the lowest its total energy, where the quantum number $l$ is 0, which means we can't get any orbital angular momentum at all from any measurement which won't collapse the state.

It's particularly weird to make a stable state from two non-rotating objects, though QM never fit in my intuition all the time.

Is there any good interpretation or analog, like Bohr's phenomenological model bridging the CM and QM?

Comment: First of all, forget everything that you have heard about "collapse", it's not a useful picture (whatever it was meant to convey in the past). A ground state is the energetically lowest state of the system and it simply has nowhere else to go. That angular momentum is quantized is simply a fact of quantum systems and all interactions with electromagnetic fields have to happen in  multiples of these quanta, which in case of the field we call "photons". The field gives up one unit aka "a photon" and the atom gains one, i.e. it is now in a state with raised angular momentum. Think zero sum game.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the interesting description. But by the mention of forgetting the concept of collapse, what do you mean? It is the concept even in Griffiths!

Comment: I mean that you should forget about it and use the chapters of textbooks (no matter how popular in your region of the world) that still try to claw something from a failed concept as doorstops.

Comment: You are saying the Copenhagen interpretation of QM failed, right? But I have learned that we can not determine which interpretation is more desirable when they output the same results. Do you have any opposite opinion for that statement?

Comment: The Copenhagen interpretation doesn't need the "collapse of the wavefunction", which is a pretty empty term that doesn't actually allow us to predict anything. It's just one of those magical terms that people think should help them to understand something when, in reality, it just deflects from the obvious. If you look into the history of quantum mechanics, you will see that the 1920s were a time of confusion, the 1930s a time of redirection and by the 1940s the smartest "quantum mechanics" (like Dirac) had really moved on to the full theory, which is about the quantization of fields.

Comment: The collapse in the text is indicated to, I think, the phenomenon that an interaction between originally far-distanced systems cause some kind of disturbance for the state of the system.(like the situation an electron is illuminated by EM wave). Could current particle physcis describe quantatively this process through the interaction of the fields of an electron and a photon, without any magical term? I don't think so, since that would be possible only if the theory is deteministic.

Comment: I mean whatever the actual term indicating that phenomena is used, the essential concept can not be thrown away from us or replaced by essentially different concept. The term collapse is nothing but just a word emphasizing the probabilistc aspect of the universe. Using which term is not an important issue, is it?

Comment: The Copenhagen interpretation describes all of this without the use of any magical terms. The relationship between initial state and final state with and without measurement is clearly defined in its framework. What gets people upset is that there is no microscopic explanation how this happens. Well, surprise! Newton doesn't tell us anything about why $F=ma$ is the correct formula, either. It doesn't have to and neither does single particle QM have to give us a detailed microscopic theory. A slight extension of it does, though, see decoherence and the density matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bohr's model is the best you can do as a classical analogy for discrete quantum bound states.  There is no classical analogy that explains how the $\ell=0$ state manages not to collide with the nucleus.  And there's a good reason that there is no classical explanation for this:  The fact that the electron in the ground state of hydrogen does not "fall to the center" is entirely a product of the uncertainty principle, which forces it to spread out in space.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I have an extra question? How did you write curly ell? I tried with backslashell between dollar signs, but failed.

Comment: LaTeX $\ell$ should produce that character, so I'm not sure what problem you are having.